# accessing json in postman BDD syntax

Tags: json, get, bdd, postman

I am trying to write tests (GET requests) in BDD syntax as in 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/postman-bdd

The json response can be as below which can be displayed in postman using `console.log(response.body)`;

```
{
    "Id1": {
        "a": 84,
        "b": 74,
        "c": 7,
        "d": 3,
        "e": 91
    },
    "Id2": {
        "a": 25,
        "b": 51,
        "c": 93,
        "d": 97,
        "e": 1
    }
}
```

Pls let me know how can I access the value of keys like a,b,c for Id1 and Id2 in BDD syntax.

I tried `console.log(response.body.Id1);` and `console.log(response.body.Id1.a)` and both does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the `postmanBDD` module with an `eval()` statement, in your test. This needs to be saved as a postman global variable in order to work.

```
eval(globals.postmanBDD)

var jsonData = pm.response.json()

describe('Get Ids', () => {

  it('should return the correct Id', () => {
    expect(jsonData.Id1.a).to.equal(84)
  })
})
```

This is a [basic example](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) of extracting data from JSON objects.

As an alternative, you can now do the same thing in the latest Postman app without bringing in the external `PostmanBDD` module:

```
pm.test('Get Id value', () => {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json()
    pm.expect(jsonData.Id1.a).to.equal(84)
})
```

This test code would do the same as the first solution.

Comment: @saritha Does this answer your question?

Comment: It displays whole json data in the console but jsonData[0].Id1.a doesnot display 84 in console

Comment: Which method are you using? The one with postmanBDD or the native Postman way in the second example? I also don't know what you mean by "in the console".

Comment: What does this give you in the console - `var jsonData = pm.response.json() 
 console.log(jsonData.Id1.a)` using the same data set in the original question? The [0] was added if the data was in an array but it's not from what i can see.

Comment: I refer to postman console. It shows syntax errror unexpected'.'.

Comment: Could you update your question with images of what you are seeing in Postman and the code that you are running in the `Tests` tab. This seems like a straight forward problem to solve, just need more visual aids.

Comment: It worked with this:  expect(jsonData[Id1][a]).to.equal(84); Thanks for your help :) Got this idea to retrive jsonData in BDD from this post :)